# Can I play WoW without internet access?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I cant use internet for games, it uses up too much of my monthly bandwidth. I'd also really like to try the game without using too much of my bandwidth.

Comment: If you want a "massive RPG" experience without having to go online, perhaps you'd be better served with one of the Elder Scrolls games - Skyrim is the latest, although Oblivion is also excellent and likely to be had cheaply.

Comment: Aside from the excellent suggestion of the Elder Scrolls games, if you have a ps2.. or a ps3 the .HACK series is pretty dang close to the mmo experience without all that messy internet and people getting in the way. There was two series on the ps2, I would suggest the first series first since it gives a good back story to whats going on.

Comment: It sounds likes you are worried about downloading the game more than playing it? Downloading the game itself will be close to 10 gb.

Comment: @agent86 The only mmo-ish feature of Skyrim is lots of quest and large maps,but since monsters don't respawn (both in world and in dungeons) it doesn't give you even close feel to the MMO.For offline MMO-ish experience i would suggest Kingdoms of Amalur,even lots of game reviewers said that the game feels like offline MMO and its graphicaly similiar to WoW while Skyrim isn't.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ Monsters in Skyrim DO respawn, plus it has a very open world, lots of quests, some even repeatable, no forced path... I can't see how you could be closer to an MMO without adding Multiplayer...

Comment: @Jupotter I didn't notice they respawn,so if they do it really takes them a lot of time lol .Anyway who needs Skyrim when you have Amalur.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it is an online game and has no offline component.

Comment: Even if I buy the cd from the store?

Comment: Even if you buy the CD from the store. You buy the client and the game is played on Blizzard servers.

Comment: Consider this: WoW doesn't use much bandwidth, except for patch and update distribution. ["While idle, the game will typically use between 1 and 7 KB/sec downstream (depending on how busy the area is) and less than 1 KB/sec upstream. While being more active, bandwidth usage is typically between 10 and 20 KB/sec downstream and 1 or 2 KB/sec upstream."](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/how-much-bandwidth-does-world-of-warcraft-use)

Comment: Wow, that's actually quite a lot. 45MB an hour. That can become 1GB a week(23 hours of gameplay) per person. :O I'm not sure how other games compare. Glad I don't have a download limit.

Comment: @Doomsknight 1 GB per week is not that much. Most people spend more than that on a single day, even if they don't spend time on video streaming websites. My bandwidth use for WoW is about 3GB, or 1% of my total cap, per month, even when including addons.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Maybe not so bad now, but 3 years ago when 10GB download limits werent unheard of.. 1GB per week ~ 4GB per month per person. 3 people is over the limit, 2 is at the limit, leaving not much for other things.
As you state, 3GB is 1% for you, so i assume your cap is ~300GB a month So it is clearly not an issue for you. But this is completely different to someone on a 10GB cap or even 20GB.

Answer (score 9):

Minimum System Requirements for World of Warcraft

Windows® System XP/XP64/Vista/Vista64/7** OS (with the latest Service Packs or updates):

- Intel Pentium 4 1.3 GHz or AMD Athlon XP 1500+
- 1 GB or more of RAM
- NVIDIA® GeForce® FX or ATI Radeon™ 9500 video card or better
- 25.0 GB available HD space
- 4X DVD-ROM drive (Downloadable Installer also available)
- **Broadband Internet connection**
- Keyboard/mouse

The whole article can be found [here](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/minimum-system-requirements-for-world-of-warcraft)

So you need to have in order to play.

Comment: You can play on a Mac too :) (Maybe it will be useful for thoses who don't know)

Answer (score -2):

With the new Battle.net desktop application you can but you cannot play with other people. It acts like a private server for offline use only. If you cant connect to Battle.net or you cant connect to your internet you can select the "World of Warcraft" game client instead of the "World of Warcraft - (Whatever Expansion)" game client. This will give you the chance to play World of Waraft by yourself but you can only play to level 60 as it is a vanilla with the latest landscapes. You have to start from scratch and even though i said "It acts like a private server for offline use only" you can play it with internet but nothing will be saved from your offline time.

Comment: Can you provide any source on this? I always assumed that WoW would not let you log in without an internet connection (but I never played the game).